# Does generation numbering in Google Cloud Storage allow you to identify the order of version creation?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if you could do something akin to optimistic locking in GCS - if I am writing the same file simultaneously, I'd like to identify which one was written first - one way to do this would be if generation numbering was sequential or otherwise had a way to let me know which was written first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generations are not guaranteed to be in creation order - please see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/gs-announce/XdSq25nsHio/-GuZxzyOAwAJ) announcement.